# Changing the position of image button in a table view cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UITableView` with an image button in front of each cell, and I want to adjust the coordinates of that `UIButton`. The relevant piece of code written in `cellForRow` is as follows:

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed "unchecked.png"];
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);** //changing the coordinates here doesn't have any effect on the position of the image button.
 button.frame = frame1; // match the button's size with the image size 
 [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // set the button's target to this table view controller so we can interpret touch events and map that to a NSIndexSet [button addTarget :self action: @selector(checkButtonTapped:event) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: thats not the relevant code the relevant code is whether you handled tableview cell caching properly.

Comment: write your full cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: where are you adding your button ?

Comment: Did you ever add the button as subview to the cell's contentView? Please provide the full code of the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 0):

The default layout of `UITableViewCell` is [`imageView`][`textLabel`][`accessoryView`]. You can't change that.

If you want to arbitrarily position an image in your `UITableViewCell` you must add a `UIImageView` to the cell's `contentView`.

Comment: The default layout could be changed by subclassing UITableViewCell and overwriting its layoutSubviews method.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the frame of a view sets its position relative to its super view, so you need to make your button a subview of the cell before setting its frame.

This however, this should not be done in cellForRowAtIndexPath, as this means you are allocating a new button each time the table view "reuses" a cell. 
You should create your button, and set its frame when you init the table view cell, so that you are only creating one button per cell.

So what you want is a UITableViewCell subclass with an init method that looks something like this.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage.png"];
        [self addSubview:button];
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    }
    return self;
}
```